# Toolbar in matplotlib not working in tkinter canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am trying to create a interactive 3d plot that can be rotated, I was able to do this using the following, however I am unable to reset the orientation when I click on the home button. I tried all the answers posted before me none seem to work.

matplolib version - 3.2.2

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
np.random.seed(1968001)

def randrange(n, vmin, vmax):
    '''
    Helper function to make an array of random numbers having shape (n, )
    with each number distributed Uniform(vmin, vmax).
    '''
    return (vmax - vmin) * np.random.rand(n) + vmin


fig = Figure()

# Unable to have rotation otherwise so defined this function
def func():
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

    n = 100

    # For each set of style and range settings, plot n random points in the box
    # defined by x in [23, 32], y in [0, 100], z in [zlow, zhigh].
    for m, zlow, zhigh in [('o', -50, -25), ('^', -30, -5)]:
        xs = randrange(n, 23, 32)
        ys = randrange(n, 0, 100)
        zs = randrange(n, zlow, zhigh)
        ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, marker=m)

    ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
    ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')


top = tk.Tk()

top_frame = ttk.Frame(top)
top_frame.pack()

canv = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=top_frame)
canv.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1)
func()
canv.draw()
toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(canv, top_frame)
toolbar.update()

top.mainloop()
```

By home button this is what I mean
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Yzm8.png)

Edit 1: I've changed the plt.figure to figure.Figure as pointed out by [Henry Yik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9284423/henry-yik), but still, it's not working

Comment: Use `matplotlib.figure.Figure` instead of `pyplot`. See the official sample [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_tk_sgskip.html).

Comment: Hey, I tried that but still, nothing happens when I click home button